# Regex Question - One or more spaces outside of a quote enclosed block of text

Tags: java, regex, quotes

I want to be replace any occurrence of more than one space with a single space, but take no action in text between quotes.

Is there any way of doing this with a Java regex? If so, can you please attempt it or give me a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another approach, that uses a lookahead to determine that all quotation marks after the current position come in matched pairs.

```
text = text.replaceAll("  ++(?=(?:[^\"]*+\"[^\"]*+\")*+[^\"]*+$)", " ");
```

If needed, the lookahead can be adapted to handle escaped quotation marks inside the quoted sections.

Answer (score 2):

When trying to match something that can be contained within something else, it can be helpful to construct a regular expression that matches both, like this:

```
("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")|(  +)
```

This will match a quoted string or two or more spaces.  Because the two expressions are combined, it will match a quoted string OR two or more spaces, but not spaces within quotes.  Using this expression, you will need to examine each match to determine if it is a quoted string or two or more spaces and act accordingly:

```
Pattern spaceOrStringRegex = Pattern.compile( "(\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\")|(  +)" );

StringBuffer replacementBuffer = new StringBuffer();

Matcher spaceOrStringMatcher = spaceOrStringRegex.matcher( text );

while ( spaceOrStringMatcher.find() ) 
{
    // if the space group is the match
    if ( spaceOrStringMatcher.group( 2 ) != null ) 
    {
        // replace with a single space
        spaceOrStringMatcher.appendReplacement( replacementBuffer, " " );
    }
}

spaceOrStringMatcher.appendTail( replacementBuffer );
```

Answer (score 0):

text between quotes : Are the quotes within the same line or multiple lines ?

Answer (score 0):

Tokenize it and emit a single space between tokens.  A quick google for "java tokenizer that handles quotes" turned up:
[this link](http://www.koders.com/java/fid8C21DD2469686C91A0A2E6F25C36DFB659D267DB.aspx?s=file:semap*.java)

YMMV

edit: SO didn't like that link.  Here's the google search link: [google](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHMP_enUS291&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java+tokenizer+that+handles+quotes).  It was the first result.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't use Java, but this RegExp could do the trick:

```
([^\" ])*(\\\".*?\\\")*
```

Trying the expression with RegExBuddy, it generates this code, looks fine to me:

```
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("([^\" ])*(\\\".*?\\\")*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= regexMatcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            // matched text: regexMatcher.group(i)
            // match start: regexMatcher.start(i)
            // match end: regexMatcher.end(i)

            // I suppose here you must use something like
            // sstr += regexMatcher.group(i) + " "
        }
    }
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

At least, it seems to work fine in Python:

```
import re

text = """
este  es   un texto de   prueba "para ver  como se comporta  " la funcion   sobre esto
"para ver  como se comporta  " la funcion   sobre esto  "o sobre otro" lo q sea
"""

ret = ""
print text  

reobj = re.compile(r'([^\" ])*(\".*?\")*', re.IGNORECASE)

for match in reobj.finditer(text):
    if match.group() <> "":
        ret = ret + match.group() + "|"

print ret
```

Answer (score 0):

After you parse out the quoted content, run this on the rest, in bulk or piece by piece as necessary:

```
String text = "ABC   DEF GHI   JKL";
text = text.replaceAll("( )+", " ");
// text: "ABC DEF GHI JKL"
```

Answer (score 0):

Jeff, you're on the right track, but there are a few errors in your code, to wit: (1) You forgot to escape the quotation marks inside the negated character classes; (2) The parens inside the first capturing group should have been of the non-capturing variety; (3) If the second set of capturing parens doesn't participate in a match, `group(2)` returns null, and you're not testing for that; and (4) If you test for **two or more** spaces in the regex instead of *one or more*, you don't need to check the length of the match later on.  Here's the revised code:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    String text = "blah    blah  \"boo   boo boo\"  blah  blah";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "(\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\")|(  +)" );
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = p.matcher( text );
    while ( m.find() ) 
    {
      if ( m.group( 2 ) != null ) 
      {
        m.appendReplacement( sb, " " );
      }
    }
    m.appendTail( sb );
    System.out.println( sb.toString() );
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool.  I should have done this in the form of a comment, but with 300 characters and no formatting, that just wasn't possible.