# Regex matching quoted string but ignoring escaped quotation mark

Tags: java, regex, quotes

What I want to know is how to modify following regex: `\".*?\"` so it will ignore escaped " character (`\"`) so it won't end matching at `\"`.

For example:

```
parameter1 =  "      fsfsdfsd \"      "   parameter2 =   "   fsfsfs   "
```

I want to match:

`"      fsfsdfsd \"      "`

and

`"   fsfsfs   "`

but not

`"      fsfsdfsd \"      "   parameter2 =   "   fsfsfs   "`

etc...

Comment: So, you mean capture everything between the two quotation marks??

Comment: yes, but lazily so it will match the shortest string in quotation marks.

Comment: Give us a string example and what you expect to get out from it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Regex for matching quoted string with escaped quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498635/java-regex-for-matching-quoted-string-with-escaped-quotes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this one:

```
"(?:\\"|[^"])*"
```

It matches `"test \"` though(you can probably avoid that using lookbehind). Escape the character if you need using `\`

[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hN0jG4)

Answer (score 4):

I usually handle this sort of task by figuring out what are the *elements* that can appear between quote marks.  In this case, each element can be:

1. any character that is not `\` or `"`;
2. the two-character sequence `\"`;
3. a `\` that is not followed by `"`.

You can expand this if desired, by allowing `\\` to represent `\`, for instance, or allowing other escapes; it should be pretty simple to modify the above list.

Then the regular expression just follows the rules in the list:  **Note: this is a regex and not a Java string literal**

```
"(([^\\"]|\\"|\\(?!"))*)"
```

which means that, within the quote marks, we match one or more of: (1) a character other than `\` or `"` (the character class); (2) the sequence `\"`; (3) `\` not followed by `"` (negative lookahead).  Of course, the Java string literal looks pretty ugly:

```
"\"(([^\\\\\"]|\\\\\"|\\\\(?!\"))*)\""
```

(Note: not tested.)

Answer (score 0):

You will need negative lookbehind in your regex:

```
(?<!\\\\)\".*?(?<!\\\\)\"
```

Answer (score 0):

correct regexp for matching strings between quotes will be:

```
    "([^\\"]+|\\.|\\\\)*"
```

but besause in java slashes need to be escaped, the result expression will be:

```
    Pattern.compile("\"(?:[^\\\\\"]+|\\\\.|\\\\\\\\)*\"");
```

this expression matches slash-escaped characters and slash themselve, for example:

```
    ... "123 \\\" 456 \\" ...
              ^       ^ slash literal
              ^
              ^ slash literal + escaped quote
```

regexp written in comments above will fail on this example